# Captured Image not Showing in Imageview

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have tried one Camera App that successfully captured an Image but it does not showing in ImageView please help me to solve it.
when I go to take the picture and select the check mark button to use the picture I run across an error while trying to display the image back into my ImageView on the app.

Here is Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView result;

static final int REQEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button click= (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    result= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
            {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap =(Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        result.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

}

And Here is XML file for

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Capture Image"
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    />
```

Thanks for Help in Advance.

Comment: Whats your targetSdk?

Comment: In onActivityResult(), correct the if condition `if (requestCode==REQEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){`

Comment: API Level 15 and above

Comment: Where is your error log?

Comment: 07-22 14:16:33.584 26483-26551/com.example.hp.camera E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Comment: have you try without set property of   android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="300dp"...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **guarantee that you have all the required permissions** in your **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Try the following :

Define the path where you want to store the picture with :

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/image.jpg";
```

1) Use the following method to invoke the camera :

```
protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

2) To capture the Camera's activity result (whether the user takes a picture or cancels it)

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode);
        switch (resultCode) {
            case 0:
                Log.i("PhotoApp", "User cancelled");
                break;
            case -1:
                onPhotoTaken();
                break;
        }
    }
```

3) Implement the following method to parse the result from the

```
    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Hello Nitin. 
Check the updated post! Forgot to add the first basic requirement for handling with device storage (permissions).

Regards,

Comment: Can you please post the Logcat stacktrace for that specific moment? Would be great to check it.